# Proper Way to Subscribe to 'robot_description' from a ros2_control Controller?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, ros2-control

[image: node&topic graph]

Hello,

I am interested in making my controller subscribe to the robot_state_publisher node to gather the hardware description of the robot. This approach seems better than providing robot_description parameter, as it is how the controller_manager does.

My question is: Is there a proper way to achieve this without creating a new robot_state_publisher that publishes to a specific destination (in my case, the controller's ~/robot_description)? This method seems to lack flexibility.

I would greatly appreciate any advice from this wonderful community. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We added this recently to the controller_interface, but only on rolling because it is breaking API. Is it feasible that you upgrade to rolling? See [this PR](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/pull/949) for how to use the URDF from your controller.

If you have to stay on humble, you have to add a subscriber to the controller subscribing to the `/exo_controller/rrbot_description` topic.